# Get The author and title of a PDF file without using third party lib on OSX

Tags: macos, pdf, core-graphics, metadata

I am trying to retrieve the author and title of a PDF file under OSX only using CG*** functions, I mean without using third party library.
However I have no idea where to begin.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the CGPDFDocumentRef pointer that represents your PDF file you call:

```
CGPDFDictionaryRef docInfo = CGPDFDocumentGetInfo(pdfDocumentRef);
```

From the docInfo dictionary you can retrieve the Author and Title entries which are PDF strings:

```
CGPDFStringRef authorRef;
CGPDFDictionaryGetString(docInfo, "Author", &authorRef);
CGPDFStringRef titleRef;
CGPDFDictionaryGetString(docInfo, "Title", &titleRef);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I get the possible values like "Title", "Author" ?

Comment: PDF specification: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf, section 14.3.3